# optional capture group syntax

Tags: regex

I'm capturing the leading sign character, if present, separate from the following digits.

So `([+-]?)(\d+)` or `([+-])?(\d+)`?

They both appear to work, according to my (limited) testing. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: The first will always capture *something* there, which may be the empty string. The second will not. Depends on the language and the mechanics of what happens when a capture group is not matched, but one might find that the empty string is easier to work with than a (possibly) completely non-matched group

Comment: @CertainPerformance: The other way round.

Comment: @Yunnosch It might be a good starting point, but I don't have much cross-language experience to point to a *specific* situation where an optional group would be clearly unwieldy. If you can demonstrate, feel free to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`([+-]?)` vs `([+-])?` is an edge case of a bad practice. We can see the distinction when we apply the same idea to the other capture.

```
(\d+) vs (\d)+
```

Both regexes match one or more digits. The first says to capture at least one digit. The second says to capture one digit multiple times; only the last digit will be captured.

[Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/0IUsHt/2).

`([+-]?)` vs `([+-])?` is the same but with (almost) no consequence. They both match zero or one + or -. The first says to capture zero or one + or -. The second says to capture one + or - zero more times. They're subtly different.

If we take `123`, `([+-]?)` will match, but `([+-])?` will not. We can see the distinction in Ruby.

```
p "123".match(/([+-])?(\d+)/)
#<MatchData "123" 1:nil 2:"123">

p "123".match(/([+-]?)(\d+)/)
#<MatchData "123" 1:"" 2:"123">
```

Note the difference in the first capture group. In the first regex the first capture did not match. In the second regexp, the first captured an empty string; a valid match of `[+-]?`.

This particular example *probably* will have no consequence, but `([+-]?)(\d+)` is preferred because `([+-])?(\d+)` is of a class of regex goofs. In sum, put the complete description of what you're capturing inside the capture group.

---

Note that no matter what, there are still only two capture groups.